# Spread one column into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm having a data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  student=c("Amy", "Bob", "Cal", "Doe","Raz","Viz"),
  A=c(9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9),
  B=c(6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7))
```

I need to transform this data frame into this format:

```
  Amy Bob Cal Doe Raz Viz
A   9   7   6   8   6   9
B   6   7   8   5   6   7
```

I guess this is achieved using `tidyr` package in R. I'm not sure how to implement it to get the desired output.

Can anyone help me to get the expected output?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -student) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = student,values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  name    Amy   Bob   Cal   Doe   Raz   Viz
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         9     7     6     8     6     9
2 B         6     7     8     5     6     7
```